# Condition for synchronizing clocks in the special relativity paper

Tags: special-relativity, time

I'm reading Einstein's special relativity paper and couldn't understand the condition for synchronizing given in the following paragraph taken from the paper -

> If at the point A of space there is a clock, an observer at A can determine the time values of events in the immediate proximity of A by finding the positions of the hands which are simultaneous with these events. If there is at the point B of space another clock in all respects resembling the one at A, it is possible for an observer at B to determine the time values of events in the immediate neighbourhood of B. But it is not possible without further assumption to compare, in respect of time, an event at A with an event at B. We have so far defined only an “A time” and a “B time.” We have not defined a common “time” for A and B, for the latter cannot be defined at all unless we establish by definition that the “time” required by light to travel from A to B equals the “time” it
> requires to travel from B to A. Let a ray of light start at the “A time” $t_A$ from
> A towards B, let it at the “B time” $t_B$ be reflected at B in the direction of A,
> and arrive again at A at the “A time” $t'_A$ . In accordance with definition the two clocks synchronize if $$t_B - t_A = t'_A - t_B$$

Suppose $t_A$ is 2:00, $t_B$ is 4:00 and $t'_A$ is 6:00 clock. So, the condition given in the above paragraph holds, but is this really sufficient to say that clocks at A and B are synchronized? What if the clock at B showed different times corresponding to $t_A$, $t'_A$ like 1:00 and 7:00?

Edit: Adding a diagram to show explain better
[image]

Is the case in the diagram possible? Also, it would help if someone could provide a simple definition of what it means to synchronize two clocks?

Comment: "By What if the clock at B showed different times corresponding to $t_A$
, $t′_A$ like 1:00 and 7:00?", do you mean $ t_B = 4, \  t_A =1, \ t_{A}' =7 $?  In that case, $(t_B - t_A) = (4 -1) = 3$ and  $(t'_A - t_B) = (7-4) =3$, so the conditions for synchronisation in your second example **are** met. I think you need to give a better clearer example. Please specify exactly what time B is reading in the second case rather than a corresponding time.

Answer (score 1):

> What if the clock at B showed different times corresponding to $t_A$, $t'_A$ like 1:00 and 7:00?

That is not possible if the two clocks are stationary relative to each other. There are only two events of interest here, which are the light leaving A and arriving back at A respectively. Since there is no relative velocity, the two clocks are in the same reference frame and therefore must give the same $\Delta t$ between the two events.

If clock B shows 1:00 when the light leaves A, it must show 5:00 when the light arrives back at A. What the last line is saying is that the standard Einstein synchronization convention defines the clock at B to be halfway between $t_A$ and $t'_A$ so that the one-way speed of light is isotropic. In other words, according to this convention, clock B is synchronized to clock A if it shows $(t_A + t'_A)/2$ at the instant when the light reflects. So if clock B showed 1:00 when the light leaves A, it is not synchronized to A.

Answer (score 0):

> Suppose $t_A$ is 2:00, $t_B$ is 4:00 and $t′_A$ is 6:00 clock. So, the
> condition given in the above paragraph holds, but is this really
> sufficient to say that clocks at A and B are synchronized? What if the
> clock at B showed different times corresponding to $t_A$, $t′_A$ like
> 1:00 and 7:00?

I am going to interpret your last line as asking what if B showed a time of 1:00 or 7:00 when $t_A= 1$ and $t'_A = 4$ as in the original specification.

If the signal left A at $t_A = 1:00$ and arrived at B at time $t_B = 1:00$ that would indicate that the either the light traveled instantaneously from A to B or cock B is not synchronized correctly.

If the signal left A at $t_A = 1:00$ and arrived at B at time $t_B = 7:00$ and returned to A at time $t'_A = 4:00$ that would indicate signal took 6 seconds to travel from A to B and -3 seconds to return to A. i.e. the return signal arrived at A before it left B. Since in relativity we assume the two way speed of light is constant and by convention (and it is only a convention) we specify that that the one way speed of light is isotropic, clearly something is wrong and the clocks have not been set up correctly.

To comply with the convention of isotropic speed of light we simply have to set $t_B$ equal to $(t'_A -t_A)/2$. Then everything works out nicely.